# RxJS sending multiple unique ajax requests on event

Tags: javascript, ajax, events, rxjs, reactive-extensions-js

If I have an event type; say a click event. That I want to fire 3 unique ajax requests for but I want to subscribe to the final result of all 3 requests

What is the proper design pattern for this sequence.

My current code block looks something like this

```
$rootScope.$eventToObservable('selectUser')
    .throttle(500)
    .map(data => {
        return angular.copy(data.additionalArguments[0].entity);
    })
    .select(d => {
        return {
            Member: MemberService.getMember(d.ID),
            otherData: MemberService.dataOtherData(d.ID),
            Notes: MemberService.getNotes(d.ID),
            Log: MemberService.getLog(d.ID)
        }
    })
    .switchLatest() //Code current dies here with an object is not a function error. I believe because the return object is not an obserable. But not sure what the proper design pattern is.
    .subscribe(model => {
        //I would like that model would contain an object with the result of the 3 responses above.
        $scope.model = model;
});
```

Comment: I missing bit of the code. all the MemberService.get methods return a promise 

`var deferred = this.$http.get(ServiceUrl + '/Users/Get/' + id);

return this.rx.Observable.fromPromise(deferred).map((response) => { return response.data; });`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `zip` to synchronize your requests. `zip` will cause all observables to be subscribed, and yield each time all of those observables fire. So, once the `n`th item from each observable is yielded, zip will yield it's `n`th value, which is created by using the `n`th values from the original observables.

Once you have that, can you use `switchLatest`, which works on `Observable<Observable<T>>`, and makes sure it's always subscribed to the latest observable. So, if you select a new user, it'll just unsubscribe from any pending request, and subscribe to the next one instead.

```
$rootScope.$eventToObservable('selectUser')
    .throttle(500)
    .map(data => {
        return angular.copy(data.additionalArguments[0].entity);
    })
    .map(entityToExpandedData).switchLatest()
    .subscribe(model => {
        $scope.model = model;
    });

function entityToExpandedData (entity) {
    return Rx.Observable
        .zip(
            MemberService.getMember(d.ID),
            MemberService.dataOtherData(d.ID),
            MemberService.getNotes(d.ID),
            MemberService.getLog(d.ID),
            makeExpandedData
        );
}

function makeExpandedData (member, otherData, notes, log) {
    return {
        member:     member,
        otherData:  otherData,
        notes:      notes,
        log:        log
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, I like your implementation. It looks like actual issue us the `return angular.copy...` I tried replacing it with just a simple ID `return 123` and I get object is not a function from Disposable.dispose. Am I miss understanding the map function? I can return any object, type I want correct? Even single values? string, int, etc.

Comment: Ultimately your answer for Rx.Observable.zip() answered my question. However there were 2 bugs. Firstly .zip() took a series of functions with the last one before the makeExpandedData. Not an array[] of api requests. Secondly the main issue I had was that the rx.angular $eventToObservable was firing the dispose event for some reason.

Comment: You're right! It's `.zip(a,b,c,...)`. Interesting though. I feel like I've used `.zip([a,b,c], ...)` before... oh well. Can you expand on what you mean by $eventToObservable firing the "dispose event"?

Comment: @ChristopherHarris When you use zip this way, are the server response objects in the array in the same order as the requests are listed?

Comment: @claireablani `switchLatest` will only yield results from the latest observable, therefore the order of results will be maintained, but results yielded from prior observable will filtered out.